# how to validate element if it is displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqbootstrapvalidation

I have a form of two elements, the first one is always required, while the second depends on the value of the first element, so if the value of first element equals to `Fashion Designers`  or `Fashion Illustrators`, the second element display will be block and the second element will be required, while if the value of the first element is anything else, the second element will still displayed none and not required.

here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id='career' enctype="multipart/form-data">    

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 paddingleft">

            <div style="margin-bottom:20px" class="form-group"> 
                <select  id="vacancy" name="vacancy" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select career</option>
                    <option value="Fashion Designers">Fashion Designers</option>
                    <option value="Fashion Illustrators">Fashion Illustrators</option>
                    <option value="Tailor">Tailors</option>
                    <option value="Tailor's Assistant">Tailor's Assistants</option>
                    <option value="Human Resources">Human Resources</option>
                    <option value="Marketing coordinators">Marketing Coordinators</option>
                    <option value="Sales coordinators">Sales Coordinators</option>
                    <option value="Accountants">Accountants</option>
                    <option value="Production Managers">Production Managers</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom:20px" class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="portfolio" id="portfolio">
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom:20px" class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#career')
    .bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        vacancy: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Vacancy is required.'
                },
            }
        },
        portfolio: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Portfolio is required.'
                },
                callback: {
                    message: 'Portfolio is required.',
                    callback: function (value, $field) {
                        if ($field.style.display === 'none') {
                            return true;
                        } else if (value != null) {

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    }
});
</script>
```

I got error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/Lg4ojsac/1/  I tried you logic in fiddle ...removed document ready part ....it's working fine ...There is a problem in your bootstrap validator code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your *$field* variable. Try using jQuery to validate the visibility:

```
!$field.is(':visible')
```

Try to debug this variable and check if you can use native javascript or jQuery is the best option.

Regards.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function `

Comment: Check this link: http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/callback/, the callback function uses 3 parameters, maybe you are using the jQuery function in _validator_ parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain wat do you want to do ??  if you are going to validate the field value the add Jquery validation plugin 
      
            FULL NAME :
            
            
            PHONE :
            
            
            PIN :
            
            
            Email  :
            
            
            Password  :
            
            
            Re-password  :
            
            
            Submit
          
    Jquery :

```
      <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            //validation rules
            $("#test").validate({

                rules: {
                  "fullname": {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },  
                    "phone": {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    },
                    "pin": {
                        required: true,
                        number: true,
                        rangelength : [3, 5]
                    },
                    "email": {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                        },
                    "pwd": {
                        required: true,

                        },
                        "Rpwd": {
                        required: true,
                        equalTo: "#pwd"
                        }
                },
                messages: {
                    "fullname": {
                        required: "You must enter your full name",
                        minlength: "First name must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },  
                    "phone": {
                        required: "You must enter your phone number",
                        number : "Phone number must contain digits only"
                    },
                    "pin": {
                        required: "You must enter your zip code",
                        number: "Zip code must contain digits only",
                        rangelength : "Zip code must have between 3 to 5 digits"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        required: "You must enter your Email ",
                        email: "Invalid Email "

                    },
                    "pwd": {
                        required: "You must enter your Passwors",

                    },
                    "Rpwd": {
                        required: "You must enter your Re-Passwors",
                        equalTo: "Password Not Match"
                    },
                },
         submitHandler: function(e) {
        $.ajax({
             url: 'test.php',
            type: 'post',
         data: $('#example2').serialize(),
         success: function(response)
         {
            $('#view').html(response);
        }            
    });

}
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Here #test is field name

Comment: I am using bootstrap validator, I want to make the field is required only if its display value is block.

Comment: add require attribut over the tag    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"
                    data-bv-notempty data-bv-notempty-message="The gender is required" />